# get look up a string given a func<T,object> param

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

given this code

```
namespace GridTests
{
    public class Grid<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> DataSource { get; set; }
        IList<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();

        class Column
        {
            public string DisplayText { get; set; }
            Func<T, object> Rowdata { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to loop through the columns collection and get the Rowdata's object value  using the DisplayText.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean DisplayText should be a property on the objects returned by the function? It's not really clear...

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to be more clear.
something like this
   private string LoopUp(string displayText)
        {
            foreach (var col in Columns)
            {
                if (col.DisplayText == displayText)
                    return col.Rowdata ;// Here I want to be able to read the object value of the RowData property
                   
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<object> Search(string yourLookup)
{
    foreach(Column column in yourGridInstance.Columns)
    {
       if(column.DisplayText.Equals(yourLookup, yourStringcomparaisonOptions)
       {
          foreach(T value in yourGridInstance.DataSource)
          {
             yield return column.Rowdata(T);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**Linq version**

```
 IEnumerable<object> Search(string yourLookup)
 {
      return yourGridInstance.Columns
          .Where(column=>column.DisplayText.Equals(yourLookup, yourStringcomparaisonOptions))
          .SelectMany(c=> yourGridInstance.DataSource.Select(data=>c.RowData(data)));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still not very clear. I am not sure which T you want to supply the RowData method. If you want to run the method with every T in your DataSource enumerator, you could do something like this.

```
public void Enumerate(string displayText)
{
     Column column = this.Columns.FirstOrDefault(item => item.DisplayText == displayText);

     if (column != null)
     {
          foreach (T key in DataSource)
          {
               object value = column.Rowdata(key);
               // Do something with your value here.
          }
     }
     else
     {
         throw new ArgumentException("DisplayText not found in Columns.", "displayText");
     }
}
```

Comment: Also, you need to mark the RowData method public or internal.